# SELECT with where clause condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

In my sql oracle table i have something like this

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
P#      NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL, /* Project number     */
PTitle      VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Project title      */
Sponsor     VARCHAR2(30),         /* Project sponsor name   */
D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
Budget      NUMBER(10,2)    NOT NULL, /* Project budget     */
CONSTRAINT Project_PK PRIMARY KEY(P#),
CONSTRAINT Project_FK FOREIGN KEY (D#) REFERENCES Department(D#),
CONSTRAINT Project_CK UNIQUE (PTitle)
);

INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1001, 'Computation', 'Microsoft', 1, 25000);
INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1002, 'Study methods', 'Education committee', 3, 15000);
INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1003, 'Racing car', 'Cloud Pty Ltd', 3, 225000);
INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1004, 'Football', 'Football club', 5, 35000);
INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1005, 'Swimming', 'Education committee', 5, 125000);
```

I have to SELECT the sponsor name and total_budget for each sponsor .
so when i SELECT SPONSOR,BUDGET. what condition should i put in order the Education commitee only show once time and the budget only show (15000+125000)= 140000 ?
the output should be something like

```
 SPONSOR           total_budget
 -------------------------------
Education Commitee    140000
Cloud Pty Ltd         225000
etc....
```

Comment: `WHERE SPONSOR = 'Education commitee' LIMIT 1`

Comment: The WHERE clause is for limiting which rows are used by the query. What you're after is an AGGREGATE function (e.g. SUM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the typical usecase for the `GROUP BY` operator:

```
SELECT sponsor, sum(budget) as total_budget
FROM Project
GROUP BY sponsor
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT sponsor_name,sum(total_budget) from tablename group by  sponsor_name
```

explore "group by"
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: its correct, type mistake was there.. sorry for that